# Should I inject service factories into my Blazor pages like this?

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, entity-framework-core, blazor, blazor-server-side

I have a Blazor page that looks like this.

```
@inject IMyService MyService

<input value=@myValue @onchange="DoSomethingOnValueChanged">

@code
{

   private string myValue;

   private async Task DoSomethingOnValueChanged()
   {
      var myValue = await this.MyService.GetData(this.myValue);

      if (myValue != null)
      {
         myValue.SomeField = "some new value";
         await this.MyService.SaveChanges();
      }
   }

}
```

The service class looks like this:

```
public class MyService : IMyService
{
   private MyContext context;

   public MyService(MyContext context)
   {  
      this.context = context;
   }

   public async Task<MyObject> GetData(string id)
   {
      return await this.context.MyDataObjects.FirstOrDefaultAsync(p => p.Id == id);
   }
 
   public async Task SaveChanges()
   {
      await this.context.SaveChangesAsync();
   }
}
```

When the user changes the value in a text box, I use my service class to get some data, update it, and then save it to the database using an Entity Framework context.  The database operations are fast (they take a few seconds at most), but it is possible that the user can enter a second value before the first value is finished processing, which would then kick off a second call to `GetData` and `SaveChanges` while the first one is still processing.

One of the problems is that this results in the exception `A second operation was started on this context before a previous operation completed. This is usually caused by different threads concurrently using the same instance of DbContext.`

I can solve that problem by injecting a context factory the `MyService` constructor and create a new context each time a request is made, like this

```
public class MyService 
{
   private MyContext context;

   private IDbContextFactory<MyContext> contextFactory;

   public MyService(MyContext contextFactory)
   {  
      this.contextFactory = contextFactory;
   }

   public async Task MyObject GetData(string id)
   {
      this.context?.Dispose();
      this.context = this.contextFactory.CreateDbContext();
      return await this.context.MyDataObjects.FirstOrDefaultAsync(p => p.Id == id);
   }
 
   public async Task SaveChanges()
   {
      if (this.context != null)
      {
         await this.context.SaveChangesAsync();
      }
   }
}
```

But now that problem is that if the second call to `GetData` happens before the first call to `SaveChanges` has happened, the context that the original data was attached to has been disposed, so `SaveChanges` on the first value will fail.

Another problem is that in the actual program, `MyService` has several child service dependencies that are injected, and they also use Entity Framework contexts.  So many methods of `MyService` would cause its child services to instantiate new Entity Framework contexts as well, which leads to the same problem of some data still being in process, but its owning context was disposed.

To solve that problem, I decided to instantiate a new service each time the page's `DoSomethingOnValueChanged` method is called.  That code looks like this:

```
public interface ITypeFactory<T>
{
   Func<T> CreateFunction { get; set; }
   
   T Create();
}

public class TypeFactory<T> : ITypeFactory<T>
{
    public Func<T> CreateFunction { get; set; }

    public T Create()
    {
        return CreateFunction();
    }
}
```

**Startup.cs**

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
   services.AddTransient(f =>
   {
      ITypeFactory<IMyService> factory = ActivatorUtilities.CreateInstance<TypeFactory<IMyService>>(f);
      factory.CreateFunction = () => ActivatorUtilities.CreateInstance<MyService>(f);
      return factory;
   }
}
```

Then I inject that factory into my Razor page and create a new instance of `MyService` each time `DoSomethingOnValueChanged` gets called.

This system works and it avoids the problem of the same context getting used twice simultaneously, but I'm worried that creating a new service this frequently is going to cause a noticeable performance penalty if the services start to have a lot of dependencies injected into them, or if the amount of model configuration in the context gets really large.

1. Right now, it looks like it's taking about 0.05 seconds to create a service instance.  Will that degrade much for services with a complex dependency graph or for a lot of EF context configuration?
2. Is this service factory system a reasonable way of handling this?  I'm only able to find information about using `DbContext` factories when I search for this, and I haven't found anything that discusses using factories for services that use `DbContext`s
3. Is there a better way of handling this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd use a [Semamphore](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.semaphore?view=net-5.0) to prevent simulataneous calls to the database. Then you don't need to create a new context.

*At first I also tried, and succeeded to implement DbContextFactory - And altough I no longer got the '...second operation has started...' error, I realised I need change tracking (through a single context) across different services & components to prevent database inconsistency issues.*

In  one of my components I have multiple input fields, which has to trigger an update function at @onfocusout. If the user would quickly jump between fields by holding in the tab key, the semaphore method below would 'stack' all update actions and complete them nicely one after the other.

```
     @code {
            static Semaphore semaphore;
            //code ommitted for brevity
            
             private async Task DoSomethingOnValueChanged()
             {
                 
                try
                {
                    //First open global semaphore
                    if (!Semaphore.TryOpenExisting("GlobalSemaphore", out semaphore))
                    {
                         semaphore = new Semaphore(1, 1, "GlobalSemaphore");
                    }
    
                    while (!semaphore.WaitOne(TimeSpan.FromTicks(1)))
                    {
                        await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));
                    }
                    //If while loop is exited or skipped, previous service calls are completed.
                    var myValue = await this.MyService.GetData(this.myValue);
                    if (myValue != null)
                    {
                        myValue.SomeField = "some new value";
                        await this.MyService.SaveChanges();
                    }     
                 
                 }
                 finally
                 {
                    try
                    {
                        semaphore.Release();
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("ex.Message");
                    }
                }
            }
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, that is a good solution.  You are putting the semaphore in the Blazor component (as opposed to in the service classes), correct?

Comment: @Ben - Yes that's correct, the semaphore is used inside the method(s) of the Blazor component where it makes the call to the injected service  However, as a Semaphore works globally, you can probably also use it directly in all your services. I haven't tested this but it should also work :)

Answer (score 2):

Instantiating service like this is not super clean. You can do the following:

1. Use dbcontext factory in every method. Note that context is now scoped to the method. 'using' keyword disposes the context as soon as the method exits so you don't have to check manually.

   ```
   public async Task<MyObject> GetData(string id)
   {
      using var ctx = this.contextFactory.CreateDbContext();
      return await ctx.MyDataObjects.FirstOrDefaultAsync(p => p.Id == id);
   }
   ```
2. Pass on the entity to the update method. Use dbcontext Update() to update and save the updated entity

   ```
   public async Task SaveChanges(MyObject obj)
   {
      using var ctx = this.contextFactory.CreateDbContext();
      ctx.Update(obj);
      await ctx.SaveChangesAsync();
   }
   ```

This should fix your problems. You shouldn't need to manually instantiate the service and address the complexity that comes with it.
A few things to remember:
Blazor mostly works well on the disconnected scenarios. So you are left in charge of managing states as well as concurrency issues that arise out of it. Read about the disconnected scenario here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/saving/disconnected-entities

You can directly use DbContext in the blazor component. Read up on OwningComponentBase here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/fundamentals/dependency-injection?view=aspnetcore-5.0&pivots=server#utility-base-component-classes-to-manage-a-di-scope-1

Comment: Thank you for the answer.  One thing that concerns me about creating new contexts inside each of the service's methods is that I have an operation `ProcessData` that calls dozens of `Add`/`Get`/`Save` service methods to complete.  In that scenario, I'd be instantiating dozens of new contexts when I call `ProcessData`.  How would you handle that?

Comment: With `OwningComponentBase` would you recommend calling `GetRequiredService` each time I need a new instance of the service to handle user input?

Comment: 1. A DbContext is supposed to be lightweight, easy to create and dispose of. I don't think you should worry too much about having to create many instances of DbContext. If fact, many recommend that a DbContext should live as short as possible. Focus on right abstraction of the unit of work operation than worrying about context creation. 2. OwningComponentBase exists because you want the lifetime of DbContext to match with lifetime of the component. So you create it only once (in initialized). Just be mindful of concurrency.

Comment: I'm confused about `OwningComponentBase` restricting the lifetime.  Doesn't registering the service as transient and injecting it into the component have the same effect (on server-side anyway)?

Comment: Transients and scoped are messy in Blazor server. The problem is that there are no "HTTP API requests" that exist for the request. Everything is scoped because the SignalR connection is always on.  From the doc **"In ASP.NET Core apps, scoped services are typically scoped to the current request. After the request completes, any scoped or transient services are disposed by the DI system. In Blazor Server apps, the request scope lasts for the duration of the client connection, which can result in transient and scoped services living much longer than expected..."**

Comment: Just to follow up - I marked the other response as the answer because it fits my particular architecture better.  But thank you for your help on this question; your response taught me something and I'll certainly make use of your suggestion in other scenarios.

Comment: Thanks for writing back! I generally avoid semaphore-based solutions because they get increasingly complex. If you just want to avoid accident double posting, you can disable the input field till you await the DB call to finish. Even if you use semaphores in Blazor UI, you will not achieve true concurrency because other classes will still be able to overwrite. (semaphores are for thread safety, not specifically for database concurrency). So I prefer to follow optimistic concurrency and handle exceptions. But, of course, you would know what best suits your needs.